# How to call a task many times in Ada

Tags: loops, task, ada

I try to call a task 100 times, but it doesn't work, it seems I should create 100 entry to do that. So Could you please give some suggestions?

I am learning how to use Ada task now :-)

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO ; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Main is

   task type test1 is
      entry start;
   end test1;

   task body test1 is
   begin
      accept start;
      Put_Line("Haha");
   end test1;

   t1 : test1;
N : Integer := 10;
begin
   while N /= 0 loop
     t1.start;
     N := N - 1;
   end loop;
end Main;
```

E:\Ada Code\Simple\obj\main.exe
Haha

raised TASKING_ERROR
[2019-06-03 17:55:17] process exited with status 1, elapsed time: 01.00s

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the task will run to completion after accepting the first rendezvous. You can avoid this by adding a loop in the task body:

```ada
task body test1 is
begin
   loop
      accept start;
      Put_Line("Haha");
   end loop;
end test1;
```

(in fact, most tasks will have a loop like this)

The task now has an infinite loop, so the next step is to make sure your task terminates when your main program is complete. In this case, you can do this with a *selective accept*:

```ada
task body test1 is
begin
   loop
      select
         accept start;
      or
         terminate;
      end select;

      Put_Line("Haha");
   end loop;
end test1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, I want to iteratively call the task. Once the task is completed, I try to call it again.

Comment: You can't call a completed task, as there is nothing there to process the call. Hence the `Tasking_Error` in your original code.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem. I hope to call a completed task. Is it possible to restart a completed task?

Comment: You cannot restart a task. You can, however, create another instance of the same *task type*: `t2 : test1;` or an array of a task type: `T : array(1..100) of test1;`

Comment: In addition, follow your suggestions.  I do something as follow, it also works.
```Ada
with Ada.Text_IO ; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Main is

   procedure test1 is
      task type test11 is
         entry Start;
      end test11;
   
      task body test11 is
      begin
         accept Start;
         Put_Line("Heihei");
      end test11;
      t11 : test11;
   begin
      Put_Line("Haha");
      t11.Start;
   end test1;

N : Integer := 10;
begin
   while N /= 0 loop
     test1;
     N := N - 1;
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Comment: @ysh: For more readable code, you can [edit] your question or [add your own answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 2):

In general it is more efficient to call a task entry, passing any needed data to or from the task, than it is to start another task. There is a non-trivial overhead involved in starting and terminating a task.
An alternative to calling task entries for tasks is to implement a producer-consumer pattern using protected objects.

The following producer-consumer example creates three producers and one consumer. Each of the producers writes 500,000 messages to the shared queue. The consumer consumes all the messages produced by the producers.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Producer / Consumer example using 3 producers and 1 consumer --
-- Matches the number of tasks to a 4-core processor            --
------------------------------------------------------------------
with Ada.Containers.Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces;
with Ada.Containers.Unbounded_Synchronized_Queues;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
With Ada.Calendar; use Ada.Calendar;
use Ada.Containers;

procedure PC_v3 is
   package Integer_Interface is new
     Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces(Element_Type => Integer);
   package Unbounded_Integer_Queues is new
     Unbounded_Synchronized_Queues(Queue_Interfaces => Integer_Interface);

   My_Queue      : Unbounded_Integer_Queues.Queue;
   Num_Producers : Constant := 3;
   Max_Produced  : constant := 500_000;
   Empty_Queue   : constant Count_Type := 0;
   Start_Time    : Time := Clock;

   -- The Counter protected object below is used to count the number of
   -- completed producers. This allows the consumer to know when all the
   -- data has been processed.
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   protected Counter is
      Procedure Task_Done;
      function All_Done return boolean;
   private
      Count : Natural := 0;
   end Counter;

   protected body Counter is
      procedure Task_Done is
      begin
         Count := Count + 1;
      end Task_Done;

      function All_Done return boolean is
      begin
         return Count = Num_Producers;
      end All_Done;
   end Counter;

   -- Define the producer task type.
   -- Producer is being defined as a task type to allow multiple instances
   -- of the producer to be easily created.
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   task type Producer;

   Task body Producer is
      Value : Positive := 1;
      Finis_Time : Time;
   begin
      loop
         My_Queue.Enqueue(Value);
         Value := Value + 1;
         if Value > Max_Produced then
            Counter.Task_Done;
            Finis_Time := Clock;
            Put_Line("Producer completed in" &
                       Duration'Image(Finis_Time - Start_Time) &
                       " seconds");
            exit;  -- exit the loop within the Producer task
         end if;
      end loop;
   end Producer;

   Read_Value : Integer;
   Done_Time  : Time;

   -- Create an array of producers. There are Num_Producers in this
   -- array. The Producer tasks start executing as soon as they are
   -- instantiated in the array.
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
   The_Producers : array(1..Num_Producers) of Producer;

begin
   -- Process the values in My_Queue until all producers are completed
   -- and the queue is empty.
   -- The program main task is being used as the consumer task.
   loop
      My_Queue.Dequeue(Read_Value);
      exit when Counter.All_Done and then My_Queue.Current_Use = Empty_Queue;
   end loop;
   -- Record the time stamp when all queue processing is done
   Done_Time := Clock;

   -- print out the execution statistics
   Put_Line("Queue element peak use:" & Count_Type'Image(My_Queue.Peak_Use));
   Put_Line("Elapsed time (seconds):" & Duration'Image(Done_Time - Start_Time));
end PC_V3;
```

As you can see, the consumer keeps running until all the data is consumed, without knowing how many producers are running or how many messages are being produced. This is much more efficient than having each producer call a consumer for each message produced.